# Move subview inside UICollectionViewCell upon touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a issue in moving the frames inside `UICollectionViewCell`.
I have a small dot(made up of `UIView`) present inside the `UICollectionViewCell` and I have set the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on my `UICollectionView`. Upon panning if the dot is being touched and moved, I want to move the dot inside the cell. I am able to change the frame of dot correctly(as shown by debugger), but the same is not getting reflected on the device screen. Please can someone suggest me what could possibly be wrong. I expect that somehow I have to refresh the views so that same can be reflected on device screen.

Some points if necessary:

1) I have subclassed UICollectionViewFlowLayout and using my own layout.

2) I have kept the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on the entire `UICollectionView` and not in each `UICollectionViewCell`. I do not want to keep the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in each cell. So please do not suggest me that.

edit: 3) The project is not using autolayout.

Yes, I have tried searching on this, but I am unable to find any suitable solution.

Comment: Why do you not want to keep the gr in each cell?  Is the project using auto layout?

Comment: @danh , It is a functionality. Cannot change it. Project is not using auto layout. I forgot to add that point. Also, is it possible to change the frame dynamically inside UICollectionViewCell? I have never used it in such a way before.